# Toggle Shortcode Sanitize Title

Tags: shortcode, sanitization, characters

Wondering if anyone can help me out... here is my custom theme shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('toggle', 'shortcode_toggle');
function shortcode_toggle( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'title'      => '',
    'class'      => '',
), $atts));

$out .= '<h5 name="' .$title. '" class="toggle '.$class.'"><a class="togglelink" href="#">' .$title. '</a></h5>';
$out .= '<div class="toggle-content">';
$out .= '<div class="block">';
$out .= do_shortcode($content);
$out .= '</div>';
$out .= '</div>';
```

return $out;
}

This is located in my themes functions.php file. I want to be able to echo the title that is entered in for the toggle in the

```
<h5 name=" '.$title. '">
```

... but I need it to strip out all characters and formatting (no spaces/symbols etc)...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you strip out "all characters" you have an empty string. Exactly what do you want to strip?

Answer (score 1):

@Ravs... got it with this:

```
$title = sanitize_title($title);
```

Thank you for your help!